# Creating a file using exec in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to use a shell program that I have been left to get running. The program starts as shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>$1/logs/$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')_start.log 2>&1
```

The program is a .sh with the input ($1) being the output folder such that it is looking in /output/logs..., the program fails on the exec line, this is my first time using bash and shell scripting but I think this line essentially redirects all the standard outputs to the log file?

The program error say

```
cannot create /output/logs/20230203_12345_start.log: directory non-existent
```

should this line also create the log file if it is non existent? I don't see how you could create the .log file first as otherwise you would get the seconds part of the title wrong?

Comment: As [@Verpous pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75373195/1745001) the error message is about a missing directory, not a missing file, but to address "I don't see how you could create the .log file first as otherwise you would get the seconds part of the title wrong?" - if you did need to, you could create the file first by defining a variable to hold the file name, e.g. `out="$1/logs/$(date '+%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')_start.log"; >"$out"; exec 1>"$out" 2>&1`

Answer (score 4):

It's not complaining about the file name, it says `directory non-existent`. I/O redirection can't make directories. Create it first with `mkdir -p "$1"/logs`, then your line should work.

Comment: Always `mkdir -p "$1"/logs || exit 1` or similar to make sure you did create the directory.